# Few problems improve with age, and public health crises are no exception

Tags: meaning-in-context

> If sunshine is the best disinfectant, the opposite is also true: Dark,
>   hidden corners are great places to grow something truly horrible. **Few
>   problems improve with age, and public health crises are no exception.**
>   Transparency is “job one” for leaders in a crisis. Be clear what you
>   know, what you don’t know, and what you’re doing to learn more. You
>   can’t manage a secret, as the old saying goes.

What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Few problems improve with age, and public health crises are no exception.

The first part of the sentence establishes the fact that "few problems improve with age". This is logically equivalent to the fact that *most* problems do *not* improve as time goes on (or "with age").

The second part of the sentence is basically saying that the problem (public health crises) is not an exception to that fact. In other words, public health crises do not improve with age, but get worst. They are not one of the "few problems" which improve as time passes.

The author is basically saying that public health crises is not a problem which cannot be ignored, as it will get worst and worst over time, as most other problems do.